# Is there a way to asynchronously load twitter widget with socialite.js?

Tags: twitter, widget, social-networking, feed, asynchronous

Hi I've used the socialite.js plugin to display social network buttons but this conflicts with the standard twitter widget/feed. Is there anyway to load the widget in using socialite and do it asynchronously if possible please? Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 2):

I recently wrote an article about this exact plugin. Check it out at:

http://www.deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/lazy-loading-social-sharing-buttons/73

It covers only loading it when the social button is in viewport, but there are a few other options available too.